# Silverlight and Secure Web Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf, security

Can anyone provide advice on the following scenario?

1. On server A is a web site containing a Silverlight control that accesses data from a WCF web service.
2. On server B is a WCF web service. Server B is hosted in a protected network.
3. Service provider will allow point to point connection between server A and B so that server A can connect with server B.

However the Silverlight control runs on the client and the client workstation attempts the connection to server B.  Direct connection from the client to server B is not allowed.

Are there any options to make the silverlight control relay its request back to server A and then server A calls the web service on server B?

Only option we are aware of is to create another web service on server A that Silverlight calls.  The new web service then calls the server B web service.  This seems clunky though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last option is correct. If you cannot expose `Server B` to Silverlight clients directly you would set-up a service on `Server A` that just relays the calls.

Not really that clunky, just an extra level of indirection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just thought there may be a way of avoiding the need for the additional web service.

Answer (score 0):

create a routing service on server A